# Customise Woocommerce cart widget

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, cart, hook-woocommerce

I am trying to customise the woocommerce cart widget and make it more "visual" like the below example. I have researched and it seems I may be able to [override the woocommerce cart widget](https://www.skyverge.com/blog/overriddin-woocommerce-widgets/) with my own behaviour through the hook `woocommerce_mini_cart()`.

**End result I would like to get to:**
[image]

Is it possible to modify the core functionality of the cart widget via this approach to achieve something like this, through the *functions.php* file or would I need CSS aswell?

```
if ( ! function_exists( ‘woocommerce_mini_cart’ ) ) {
function woocommerce_mini_cart( $args = array() ) {

$defaults = array( ‘list_class’ => ” );
$args = wp_parse_args( $args, $defaults );
woocommerce_get_template( ‘cart/mini-cart.php’, $args );

}
//*MODIFY HERE?*
}
```

Alternatively does anyone know of a woocommerce plugin which could solve this?

Comment: This could be a starting point: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/108300/woocommerce-override-mini-cart-php-not-working (notice - old answer, but basic principles are still true)

Answer (score 0):

Despite of the question is not actual for its` author already,
I wanna to share some code to modify the default woocommerce_mini_cart() output:
1) The most difficult step - disable ECHO for woocommerce_mini_cart() function
2) change output HTML as you wish;
3) echo formatted HTML.

1)

```
function disable_echo_for_woocommerce_mini_cart() {
   $mini_cart_html = woocommerce_mini_cart(); 
   return $mini_cart_html;
}
```

2)

```
$mini_cart_html = disable_echo_for_woocommerce_mini_cart();
$mini_cart_html = str_replace('some_code', 'some_code_2', $mini_cart_html); // change output HTML.
$mini_cart_html = ob_get_clean();
```

3)

```
echo $mini_cart_html;
```